# How to input decimal numbers in ag-grid cells

Tags: decimal, ag-grid

Using `numericCellEditor` in such way (without `cellEditorParams`):

```
var columnDefs = [
    {
        cellEditor: 'numericCellEditor'
    },
]
```

Decumal numbers (1.25, 3.675 etc.) input is not possible. What cell editor to choose (or, maybe, how to tune `numericCellEditor`) to work with decimals, i.e. so I could edit values, and in opened editing fields I could'n print letters or other non-numeric symbols, but I could input dot or comma as decimal separator.

Answer (score 1):

Include this

```js
function isCharDecimal(charStr) {
  return '.'.indexOf(charStr) === 0;
}
```

And then isKeyPressedNumeric to

```js
function isKeyPressedNumeric(event) {
  const charCode = getCharCodeFromEvent(event);
  const charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  return isCharNumeric(charStr) || isCharDecimal(charStr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check numeric editor example [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/#example-component-editor) in the official docs.

You can modify the `isKeyPressedNumeric` function to something like -

```
private isKeyPressedNumeric(event): boolean {
    const charCode = this.getCharCodeFromEvent(event);
    const charAllowed = [".","Backspace"];
    const charStr = event.key ? event.key : String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    return this.isCharNumeric(charStr) || charAllowed.includes(charStr);
}
```

Note that this is just an example to allow decimal numbers, you can modify the implementation to suit your requirement.

Comment: But the document, you've mentioned, doesn't cover decimal numbers. And another problem with decimals in Ag-grid is that I cannot count sum in the group, using `aggFunc: 'sum'`

Comment: Updated the link

Comment: Unfortunately, this is Angular example, I try to find js solution

Comment: It will allow decimal point without checking if its already exists, i.e. '0.5' and '0.5.5' both will be allowed. So will require some additional validations with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following function

```
function isCharDecimal(charStr) {
  return !!/\./.test(charStr);
}
```

And change **isKeyPressedNumeric()** as following

```
function isKeyPressedNumeric(event) {
  const charCode = getCharCodeFromEvent(event);
  const charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  return isCharNumeric(charStr) || isCharDecimal(charStr);
}
```

*Note: This will accept more than one decimal point. :(*

Answer (score 0):

As an improvement on the solution offered by Pavel,  you could use the following to allow up to one decimal point (but not more than one).

Add this function (where this.eInput is your html input):

```js
function isCharTheFirstDecimal(charStr) {
  return !!/\./.test(charStr) && !/\./.test(this.eInput.value);
}
```

And then change isKeyPressedNumeric to:

```js
function isKeyPressedNumeric(event) {
    var charCode = this.getCharCodeFromEvent(event);
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    return this.isCharNumeric(charStr) || 
    this.isCharTheFirstDecimal(charStr);
}
```

The other functions used (which are all from the example in the ag-grid documentation here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing) are below:

```js
getCharCodeFromEvent(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    return typeof event.which == "undefined" ? event.keyCode : event.which;
}

isCharNumeric(charStr) {
    return !!/\d/.test(charStr);
}
```